# site sections won't span full width of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the sections of my site to span the full width of the screen. I had it running but something has gone wrong. The site is at:

```
http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/index2.html
```

It has to be something simple, but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions? Thanks so much. -Beth

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like you haven't removed the default margin from the `body`....try `body:margin:0`

Answer (score 1):

There's margin of 8px in the body.

Remove the margin and you are good to go.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XcKi.jpg)

Comment: I must have backed it out some way as I think it is working now. I added a new container at the bottom of the page. One key stroke can make it or break it?